# Redirect in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I made authorization on the site using the [Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) package, after authorization in the config it says:
`'home'=>RouteServiceProvider::HOME`,

`HOME` is `public const HOME = '/';`.

It turns out very inconvenient, for example, the user was leafing through the products and suddenly decided to log in / register and he was redirected to another page.

How can I change the rule in the config so that after authorization the user remains on the same page, by analogy as in the controllers:

`return redirect->back();`?

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-middleware If a user is not logged in but tries to post, the middleware will force the user to log in and will be automatically redirected to the post route, with the posted data. I can't write it out for you because I have no direct experience with Fortify.

Comment: Take a look at [this question on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-to-intended-url-jetstream-fortify), specifically post #13 where the OP provides code on how they got it to work using [this method](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects) from [Snapey](https://laracasts.com/@Snapey).

Answer (score 0):

You can use from the `url()` helper function and try this in your controller:

```
return url()->previous();
```

Or use this:

```
Redirect::back()
// or
return Redirect::to(URL::previous());
```

Comment: It's not in the Controller. `'home'=>RouteServiceProvider::HOME` is located in `configs/fortify.php`,
`public const HOME = '/'` is in `Providers/RouteServiceProvider`.